# Changing a partial view on hash change, or on navigation, angularjs, multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, binding, coffeescript

Yeoman scaffolds my app.coffee file like this:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('fooApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
])
  .config ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider
      .when '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      .otherwise
        redirectTo: '/'
```

Now lets say in my home.html file, I have links namely

- home

  - newsfeed

Where newsfeed is a child of home, so what I wanted to do is partially change the html, but not the whole page.

As of now, I only know that I can change templates whenever I assigned it at the app.coffee file, how do I change just the partial of the primary view.

Comment: wow, I should have checked the documentation first, also, I have thought that ng-include works like php include that is not dynamic. #jeez

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router it has an elegant solution in working with nested views.